# Where can we see spark output console when we run in yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm a beginner with Spark, Hadoop and Yarn. I install Spark with : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ 
and Hadoop/Yarn with : 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html. 
My aim is to run spark application on yarn cluster but I have problems.
How do we know when our setup works ? I will show you my example.
After doing my setup, I tried to run the test jar : examples/jars/spark-examples*.jar. When I run locally spark with : 
./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi , 
I see at one moment the line : "Pi is roughly 3.1370956854784273", whereas when I want to run on a yarn cluster with :
./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi     --master yarn     --deploy-mode cluster     examples/jars/spark-examples*.jar I don't see "Pi is roughly 3.1370956854784273" in the console and I don't know where I can find this. I watch the log in the Url http://localhost:8088/cluster/cluster but it doesn't appear.
Do you know where I should look ?
Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: Hello everyone, of course ! I forgot it ; ) !

Comment: Then to precise, I see that a guy have a similar problem on the site but I don't understand the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use view the same using resource manager and the application id
or by using the following command you will get the entire log for the application 
using
yarn logs -applicationId *application ID*

Comment: Hello, I try to do that in my Linux Terminal :

Comment: yarn logs -applicationId application_1549879021111_0007. But it prints : "yarn: eoor: no such option : -a" ? I understant that he don't recongnize -applicationId ?

Answer (score 2):

In yarn cluster mode, the default output console is not really your driver (where you submit your job) but the yarn logs it self.
So you can run

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1549879021111_0007 >application_1549879021111_0007.log
```

and after

```
more application_1549879021111_0007.log
```

Then you can use `/pattern` where pattern is a word or expression that you have in your print command in inside your python script. Usually, I use

```
print ('####' + expression to print + '###')
```

After I can do /### to find my print

Answer (score 1):

I encountered with the same issue and finally able to check the "Pi is roughly 3.14..." after the following steps:

First enable yarn log aggregation in every nodes by adding these lines to `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds</name>
    <value>3600</value>
</property>
```

You may need to restart yarn and dfs after modification of yarn-site.xml

Then check the logs by command line:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <applicationID>
```

[image: yarn logs -applicationId <applicationID>]
[image: Pi is roughly...]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, I tried to enter this command in my hadoop folder but the system says  : 
yarn: error: no such option: -a . I think I didn't do it correctly ? Where do you run this command ?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I just run `yarn logs -applicationId <applicationID>` in home folder (as you can see in my screenshot). Please make sure you have enable yarn log aggregation in `yarn-site.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the Spark driver container in YARN, or from the Spark UI. From there, you can go to the Executors tab, and you will see the `stdout` and `stderr` links for each one (plus, the Driver, where the final output will be).

Overtime, YARN will evict these logs, which is why you would need log aggregation enabled and the Spark History Server deployed.

---

FWIW, Cloudera is going all-in on running Spark on Kubernetes in recent announcements. Not sure what that says for having YARN (or HDFS with Ceph or S3 being popular datastores with these deployments)

Comment: OK thanks, If I good understand with Spark HIstory Sevrer I could read the output ?

Comment: That is where completed Spark tasks will aggregate their output, yes. The logs themselves are stored in HDFS

Answer (score -1):

You will have to write the console output to a file, what this will do is that it will write the output of your spark program being executed into a file, you can use **tail -f 100** on the **consoleoutfile.txt** mentioned below to see your console output.

```
./submit_command > local_fs_path/consoleoutfile.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Hello, I run this : ./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi     --master yarn     --deploy-mode cluster     examples/jars/spark-examples*.jar > hdfs://localhost:9000/user/thibault/user/thibault/consoleoutfile.txt 2>&1

Comment: But I have the following error : 
hdfs://localhost:9000/user/thibault/user/thibault/consoleoutfile.txt: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: This doesn't work when you do `--deploy-mode=cluster`. In that output file, you'll just get the URL to the Spark driver, where the logs actually are